# React Dev Build: The Operation Is Insecure With Safari or Any Mobile Browser

Tags: reactjs, safari, mobile-safari, webpack-dev-server, mobile-chrome

I have a React app. The app works as expected everywhere except, Safari for Mac and any mobile browser. All the solutions I find online are outdated and not relevant to my versions.

I've tried playing with the browserlist to no avail as well. The workarounds I've seen for webpackHotDevClient have been implemented in the release I have.

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js
node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js:60
__webpack_require__
/app/webpack/bootstrap:784
```

**webpackHotDevClient.js:60**

```
var connection = new WebSocket(
  url.format({
    protocol: window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws',
    hostname: process.env.WDS_SOCKET_HOST || window.location.hostname,
    port: process.env.WDS_SOCKET_PORT || window.location.port,
    // Hardcoded in WebpackDevServer
    pathname: process.env.WDS_SOCKET_PATH || '/sockjs-node',
    slashes: true,
  })
);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "3": "^2.1.0",
    "-": "0.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5",
    "yargs-parser": "^18.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

`npm --version` 6.14.5

Comment: I also just updated to the most recent version of react-scripts. No change.

Comment: Is this one that much of a mystery? Is there some better data to supply for clarity or troubleshooting? "Help me Obi Won, you're my only hope."

Comment: For me, this is related to localStorage I think

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same error and in my case, because a Content-Security-Policy is defined, I had to add two more entries to `connect-src` part: `ws://localhost:3000/` and `wss://localhost:3000/`.

You'll have to replace the port number above with the correct one in case you use a different port.

Please note that this is in addition to the webpackHotDevClient fix.

Comment: Brilliant! Solved it for me! =)

Answer (score 0):

Check that the cert your using is trusted. Safari doesn’t establish wss:// without the cert being explicitly trusted.

Comment: All our apps and software run behind a proxy. TLS is terminated at the proxy. To the app it should just look like a standard HTTP connection. Maybe I'm missing something.